# How to test signed application (apk) on the Hardware Devices?

Tags: android, testing

I am doing now the following:

- Export application from Eclipse
- Change device connection type to USB
- Manually copy it to the device
- Change device connection type to Sync
- Manually install that on device

Is there any way to create Eclipse Debug configuration (or something else) to do it automatically?

I need to test that on device and file should be signed since I am testing in-app purchases functionality.

Comment: Looks like some .bat or .cmd file should help me - looks like I need to generate the apk file first and then sign that in accordance with http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp

Comment: Looks like it should something like `ant release <br>   
jarsigner -verbose -keystore my-release-key.keystore bin/my_application.apk alias_name <br>     
adb -d install bin/my_application.apk`

Comment: `ant release` will do the signing and output an <application>_release.apk, so skip the jarsigner. Make it `adb -d install -r <apk>` - otherwise it will fail if the app is already installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ant for building, it will automate the whole builds process (for release as well).

The default configuration contains an install target as well, but I believe this installs the debug apk.

EDIT: you can install an apk via adb:

```
adb install <apk>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added more details to my question comments. Could you please check if this is right approach? (if so, I would need to understand how to install ant on my Windows PC)

Comment: @LA_ Ant runs fine on Windows, it is written in Java and comes with an ant.bat/ant.cmd wrapper script.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of the question:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-eclipse.html

> **Automatic and manual target modes**
>
> By default, a run configuration uses
>   the **automatic** target mode in order to
>   select an AVD. In this mode, ADT will
>   select an AVD for the application in
>   the following manner:
>
> 1) If there's a device or emulator already running and its AVD
>   configuration meets the requirements
>   of the application's build target, the
>   application is installed and run upon
>   it.
>
> 2) If there's more than one device or emulator running, each of which meets
>   the requirements of the build target,
>   a "device chooser" is shown to let you
>   select which device to use.
>
> 3) If there are no devices or emulators running that meet the
>   requirements of the build target, ADT
>   looks at the available AVDs. If there
>   is an AVD that matches the build
>   target of the project, ADT chooses
>   that AVD. If the AVD versions are
>   newer than the build target of the
>   project, ADT chooses the oldest
>   possible version of an AVD that meets
>   the project's build target
>   requirement.
>
> 4) If there are no suitable AVDs, the application is not installed a console
>   error warning tells you that there is
>   no existing AVD that meets the build
>   target requirements.
>
> However, if a "preferred AVD" is
>   selected in the run configuration,
>   then the application will always be
>   deployed to that AVD. If it's not
>   already running, then a new emulator
>   will be launched.
>
> If your run configuration uses **manual**
>   mode, then the "device chooser" is
>   presented every time that your
>   application is run, so that you can
>   select which AVD to use.

And for the second part,

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard

**Compile and sign with Eclipse ADT**

> If you are using Eclipse with the ADT
>   plugin, you can use the Export Wizard
>   to export a signed .apk (and even
>   create a new keystore, if necessary).
>   The Export Wizard performs all the
>   interaction with the Keytool and
>   Jarsigner for you, which allows you to
>   sign the package using a GUI instead
>   of performing the manual procedures to
>   compile, sign, and align, as discussed
>   above. Once the wizard has compiled
>   and signed your package, it will also
>   perfom package alignment with
>   zipalign. Because the Export Wizard
>   uses both Keytool and Jarsigner, you
>   should ensure that they are accessible
>   on your computer, as described above
>   in the Basic Setup for Signing.
>
> To create a signed and aligned .apk in
>   Eclipse:
>
> 1) Select the project in the Package Explorer and select **File > Export**.
>
> 2)Open the Android folder, select Export Android Application, and click
>   **Next**.
>
> 3) The Export Android Application wizard now starts, which will guide
>   you through the process of signing
>   your application, including steps for
>   selecting the private key with which
>   to sign the .apk (or creating a new
>   keystore and private key).
>       Complete the Export Wizard and your application will be compiled,
>   signed, aligned, and ready for
>   distribution.
>
> ---

If all this is not enough, then the option is building it with ant.
See here for some ideas (as I said in the comment, I have no experience with it):

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html

[Eclipse Android app: Run signed with real certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669586/eclipse-android-app-run-signed-with-real-certificate)

[Android Ant project reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056704/android-ant-project-reference)

http://www.alittlemadness.com/2010/05/31/setting-up-an-android-project-build/

Comment: I've seen that, but sorry I don't understand how it can help me.

Comment: You should have your phone connected through the USB with debugging on (Settings > Applications > Development > USB debugging) and no emulator running. So, unless you changed it in the android project properties, it will automatically choose for you where to install the app, in this case the phone. It's basically doing `adb -d install YOURAPK.apk` for you (the `-d` command directs adb to use only usb-connected devices).

Comment: But it doesn't sign application with my private key with such approach - so, I can not test in-app purchases.

Comment: The second link tells you how to sing it with Eclipse with your own key. I don't have Eclipse right now but I will write a step-by-step procedure later tonight.

Comment: Aleadam, I know how to sign that with Eclipse. The question is how to automate all these steps.

Comment: @LA_ You can automate that with ant - as I wrote above.

Comment: @LA_ as sstn says, of two steps are fine, then export the project from Eclipse and install with adb -d will suffice. If you want all with one click, the you will need to set up ant. I will add a couple of links above so you have a starting point, but I have no experience with ant myself.