# How can I run android app in eclipse with signed key?

Tags: android, android-keystore

Is there a way I can provide the signed key to the builder and let the app build and install onto my device using the signed key directly? or I have to export the app manually and choose the key, enter the password, and then install it on my device manually?

So simply the question is: is there a way to use signed key while building app in eclipse (Which automatically installs it on device)?

Please notice: I'm not asking asking about how to debug it, I just need to run it directly from eclipse to device with signed key.

Comment: http://chocotech.blogspot.com/2012/10/get-debug-key-and-release-key-for.html

Answer (score 2):

I have never done it but according to the docs you can. You have to configure it to run that way by giving it a path to the keystore and the password. But it looks like once you get it set up then it will be easy and do what you need.

[Run in release mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669586/eclipse-android-app-run-signed-with-real-certificate) is also a SO post about it.

Comment: Well my problem is in the setup, I can't get it to work, and the other question isn't solved too.